# Hibernate validator not working despite the correct implementation

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I am using hibernate validator and i think every thing is logically perfect I used all the right annotations and the right library jars but nothing is happening I don't know why is it the hibernate version or the Spring version I don't know FYI I am using Tomcat 8.5.

This is the controller

```
@RequestMapping("/showForm")
public String showForm(Model theModel) {

    theModel.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());

    return "customer-form";
}

@RequestMapping("/processForm")
public String processForm(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer theCustomer,
        BindingResult theBindingResult) {

    System.out.println("Last name: |" + theCustomer.getLastName() + "|");

    if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "customer-form";
    }
    else {
        return "customer-confirmation";
    }
}
```

and this is the bean class

```
@NotNull(message="is required")
@Size(min=1, message="is required")
private String lastName;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any error. Can you post that here. Also your pom.xml will be helpful too

Comment: no exceptions or errors are thrown ...

Comment: i don't even know what is the pom.xml may be it is the problem because all the documentations are talking about the apache maven as a requirement but i don't know any thing about it

Comment: Have you tried using hibernate validator NotNull with simple main class . Not in the tomcat container. May be it will give you some visibility

Comment: i tried this did not wok either

Comment: i am out of solutions i dont know what is the problem and i am new to this soo......